# Apply 3D printed look / texture

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm really new to Blender but I'm not getting how the following has been done:

I wanted to have a texture that looks like 3D printed.
After hours online and trying, I still didn't figure out a bit and I found this thread: [How to make a mesh look like it was 3D printed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-make-a-mesh-look-like-it-was-3d-printed/6238#6238)

The model from Leon Cheung (the first of the two monkeys) is exactly what I'm looking for: "I'd recommend the Wood procedural texture for this"

This might be really straight forward for you guys but i somehow don't get how this is applied...not even close. And at this point this is driving me nuts. Can't be that hard.

I'm running v. 2.83.0

Let me know if this makes sense and if you need anything else.

THANK YOU for your help!!!

[image]

Comment: Do you want the settings you have highlighted applied, or do you just want the final look?

Comment: I just wanted to have the final look of it. I'd like to download this as a glb file so it can be displayed in a 3d viewer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, I think you want a setup that looks something like this:

[image: 3DPrintEffect]

Comment: Just so i don't focus on the wrong thing: I have to learn and go through nodes whenever i want to achieve this result (using the wood texture from within blender as well?)

Comment: In short, yes. Nodes (through the shading tab) have been placed as the focus for materials since 2.8. Most of the time, you don't have to fiddle too much, they placed the Prinipled BSDF as the default shader node for any new material, and it can handle a lot. You can plug image textures into most of the inputs, and it makes it easy to arrange texture settings. Additionally (and highly recommended) is the use of the node-wrangler addon that comes built in to blender (it must be enabled) to make work even easier. It adds shortcuts like ctrl+t to add an image texture, for example.

Comment: For procedural textures (which is what this is), you will pretty much always go through a node graph such as this one."Object" and "generated" are the typical texture coordinates for procedural textures, whereas image textures generally use UV (to compliment the UV map you have made when unwrapping your model)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Christopher, i came to the point where i got lines and a similar pattern as desired but still far off from the shared photo. However, could you explain me the difference between the wave texture and the wood texture? Well, more how i could try out the wood texture, as i can not find it in any of the nodes so far. (voronoi, brick, magic textures. Everything is there but no wood texture. My goal is to reproduce his first option "Wood procedural texture")

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen a wood node. Looking through the docs, there are a few that "apparently" exist in blender 2.83, including Wood, Clouds and Stucci, but I've never seen them. Perhaps they're new (planned) Let me see about making the graph look more like the picture. l'll upload if I get it.